# Allow the user to upload a document to the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Orchard CMS V 1.6 I would like to implement a feature which (1) allows the user to upload a document (2) stores the date it was uploaded (3) Stores the id of the record uploaded

Is there a part for doing this.

I've no idea how to go about this....any suggestions welcome...thanks

**EDIT**
[image]

As I'v said i've used your advice to create a content type.
Then created a custom form and tried to add that content type(the media) to a custom form.(as explained on the link you provided http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha)

however when it appears on screen on the front end the mediaPicker box appears but it is greyed out and doesnt allow me to select it. 'Browse' and 'clear' also do nothing....Also how can i remove the option of the permalink

thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new content type with whatever name you want eg. MyFileUpload
- Add the Title, AutoRoute and Common part (common part will store the date the content item was created)
- Add a field and select the Media Picker Field (you can limit extensions to only allow .doc files if you wish and make this field required)

Something like that should work :)

Comment: In the Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord the record has appeared as 'upload file' which is what the part is called..but where are the actualy files that I upload stored to?

Comment: In the media directory in the AppData folder

Comment: Cant find them in the app data folder...I have 'dependencies, logs, sites' folder with 2 other files cache and hrestart. Although the uploaded files can be viewd from the content item section.

Comment: thanks for the replies by the way but what you have suggested is really for an admin to upload a doc. As i dont want a normal user to be able to enter a 'title' or given the option of publish and save. I just want the user to be able to upload a doc from the front end. Could you suggest how I could amend this to suit? How can i change access levels for users can you tell me?

Comment: Hey, sorry it isn't in the App_Data folder. Just look in Orchard.Web -> Media. And to put this stuff on the front end you want to use the Custom Forms module. This allows for content contributions. Check here for an example of how to use it: http://devdirective.com/post/160/how-to-create-custom-forms-in-orchard-cms-with-email-and-recaptcha But this would mean users would add a title etc. I'm not really sure what you are trying to create, but you may need to make a custom module...

Comment: ah ok...iv used the link you provided to create a form.  This custom form uses the content type I created to upload a file....but when viewed on screen the upload box is greyed out and doesnt allow me to select it...please see edit of my Q for pic